# CSS rollover states

Tags: html, css

Can someone please help me with the rollover states on this Instagram feed?

http://www.christielakekids.com/gala2015/

I can't figure out why they are showing below the images in the very bottom row.

```
.image_block div:hover .rollover        { bottom:0px; transition:all ease-in-out 0.5s;}
.rollover                               { width:100%; height:100%; background-color:rgba(92, 112, 163, 0.9); position:absolute; bottom:-100%; left:0px; display:block;}
.roll_content a                         { display:block;  font-family: 'GothamBookRegular'; color:#FFF; font-size:25px; text-decoration: none;}
.roll_content p                         { margin-top: 20px; font-family: 'GothamBookRegular';    font-size:25px; color:#FFF; line-height:30px; text-align:center; padding:3% 10% 0 10%;}
```

Comment: Are you still having a problem or have you figured it out? Viewing the link you provided everything looks fine in Chrome and IE (unless I am missing something) I suggest creating a js.fiddle showcasing your problem instead of linking directly to a website. Think about other people who may have this same issue!

Comment: It looks ok to me too. Chrome and FF.